# Deleting a card problems with Balanced API

Tags: rest, balanced-payments

I am using PHP to try delete a card from Balanced.

I have tried

```
$card = Balanced\Card::get("/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP4K6K0PWGyPtXL4LZ42sQSb/cards/CC5N3HHUDrAyvhNwQOoUd3UX");
$card->unstore();
```

and

```
$card = Balanced\Card::get("/v1/customers/CU6vs1tjxBtifgTuzKjCGtVS/cards/CC5N3HHUDrAyvhNwQOoUd3UX");
$card->unstore();
```

Note the different format on the card uri

In both cases the card disappears from balanced marketplace but;

1 - Nothing shows up in logs or activity

2 - I get an error

"An AJAX HTTP error occurred
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path:/ URI of the page
StatusText: error
Response Text:

I would really like to know if I should be able to see that a deletion has occurred via the marketplace and what response is sent by balanced.

Comment: Are you using drupal? I believe the AJAX error you're receiving is related to that.

Comment: Yes using Drupal, I was concerned that this may be linked but did not want to muddy the question with even more info.  Should I be concerned about using drupal and balanced?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the uri does not matter, both are valid endpoints.

In terms of the HTTP status for a delete it will return a 204 NO CONTENT so the response will be empty.

Comment: I get a  HTTP Result Code: 500 and balanced marketplace does not log any activity but the card is no longer returned on list all cards.

Comment: In both cases the card disappears from balanced marketplace but nothing shows up in logs or activity.

I would really like to know if I should be able to see that a deletion has occurred via the marketplace and what response is sent by balanced.

Comment: Ok, now I am seeing a response in the logs.
To be clear initially the cards were deleting but there was no log entry on balanced.  Now the cards are deleting and there is a log entry on balanced.  However I have encountered a nested ajax problem in reading this - I suspect another question if I can't work it out.